# Add flags for the compiler used by flycheck

Tags: flycheck

I am trying to run flycheck with c++-code which imports the *thread* library. *thread* requires -std=c++11 which is not used with the c/c++-gcc setting.

Is there a way to add this flag or to solve this in a some other way?

Answer (score 1):

There's an option for this called `flycheck-gcc-language-standard`.  You can find this and more options for C/C++ in the [list of supported languages](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/languages.html#flycheck-languages) in our [documentation](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/).